# Hash-maps or search tree?

Tags: sorting, data-structures, hashmap, time-complexity, trie

The problem is as follows: Given is a list of cities and their countries, population and geo-coordinates. You should read this data, save it and answer it in an endless loop of the following type:

Request: a prefix (e.g., free).

Answer: all states beginning with this prefix ("case-insensitive")
and their associated data (country + population + geo-coordinates).
The cities should be sorted by population (highest population first).

- Which data structure are the most suitable for the described problem ?

First Part : My Thoughts are hanging between Trie and Hashmap. Although i tend to the Trie more because i'm dealing with prefix requests , and Trie is basically according to ***Wikipedia*** :

**"a trie, also called digital tree and sometimes radix tree or prefix tree (as they can be searched by prefixes), is a kind of search tree—an ordered tree data structure that is used to store a dynamic set or associative array where the keys are usually strings"**.

in addition to that in terms of Storage and reading data Trie has the advantage over Hash-maps.

Second part: returning the sorted cities by population would be a little bit challenging when we speak about Time Complexity.If i'm thinking in the right direction i should save the values of the keys as lists and it will be easier to sort just the returning list , so i don't have to save it sorted to save some times.

Please share you thoughts and correct me if i'm wrong .

Comment: Is it necessary to use just one data structure?

Comment: @Coldspeed no , that's what i thought to use trie and list .

Comment: Then why not use both? Use the trie to access, sort based on population and then access data in that order.

Comment: @Coldspeed so what you mean basically what i wrote up there , meaning my idea is correct in terms of efficiency ?
but wouldn't it be more efficient to sort only the returning part and not every time i add new object ?

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. I meant, you get all the names from the tree, sort based on population, and then you return.

Comment: @Coldspeed yeah , Thanks sir , that helps a lot .

Comment: Why not just store the countries in a list, alphabetically by name? With binary search you can get the first and last countries that match the prefix, and then you can return the countries in that range, sorted by population. It has the advantage of simplicity, and the sorted list will take much less space than a corresponding trie. The trie is potentially faster than binary search, but with only 195 countries (currently), it's not going to be noticeable.

Comment: @JimMischel thanks for your answer. we are talking about cities and villages inside the countries. which is a big amount of data .inserting it in trie took O(n) , searching would be the same as in search trie . sorting this data would take O(n log n) sorting it twice would cost more , search in for the first and the last would request searching the whole list which O(n) . in term of time complexity i found it more efficient to you a prefix tree, with neglecting the storage crisis .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are pros of cons of picking vanilla tries and vanilla hashmaps. In general, for autocomplete systems, the structure of a trie is extremely useful because you're usually searching for prefixes and the user would like to see the words that begin with the string that they have just entered.

However, there is a method to make the best use of both of these data structures, it is called a **Hash Trie** (implementation: http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-hash-trie/). So the way you would implement this is by using the structure of the trie, but the final node is the actual string it refers to. In python, this is done using dictionaries instead of lists while implementing the trie.

For the second half of the question, a list would be your best bet, in essence a list of tuples (population, city) and sort by the population and return the cities. Regarding it being "easier" to sort, I'm not sure if I agree with this, easy is a relevant term and there's really no way of saying that it's easier than, maybe storing it in a tree and then returning the Pre-Order Traversal of the tree. Essentially, if you're using comparison based sort, it won't get better than **nlog (n)**.